# How to change C# console application title bar icon

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

How can i change window title bar icon in C# Console application,
i like to remove default icon and set my own application icon.I like to do it using project properties in Visual Studio. I'm using `.net framework 2.0`

[image]

Comment: @Mohit Shrivastava above question asked about "not using project properties in Visual Studio"

Comment: @Dnyanesh reference link you provide is about changing icon in executable file(.exe file).I'm asking about changing windows title bar icon..